# TypeScript type check failed to catch wrong assignment

Tags: typescript

```
class BaseClass {}

var cls:BaseClass = 1234;
```

You can try this on TypeScript playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

The code above is very simple, yet TypeScript didn't catch the mistake. Since the mistake is very obvious, it makes me wonder if I did something wrong.

Comment: If you give the class any methods or properties then this will fail to compile. It's kind of strange this is allowed on an empty class though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an error because it isn't a mistake. The BaseClass type has no members, so in a structural type system, it's a supertype of everything. If you add any members to it (that aren't also members of Number), you'll get an error:

```
class BaseClass {
    x;
}

var cls:BaseClass = 1234; // Error
```