# why can I assign a literal with unknown properties to a variable of type {}

Tags: typescript, types

The below code fails type checking with:

> Object literal may only specify known properties

```
type A = {a: number}
const a:A  = {a:42, b: 43};
```

Why then does the following succeed:

```
type A = {}
const a:A  = {a:42, b: 43};
```

What's the intuition here? What is the type that only accepts objects with value `{}` ? Clearly the type `{}` accepts a lot more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript type check failed to catch wrong assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385775/typescript-type-check-failed-to-catch-wrong-assignment)

Comment: somewhat but not exactly the same thing and doesn't answer what is the type that only accepts objects with value {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and supports structural subtyping, so object types are *open* in the sense that they do not prohibit extra unknown properties.  They are not "sealed" or "exact" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)):

```
type A = { a: number }
const a2 = { a: 42, b: 43 };
const a3: A = a2; // no error
```

This supports interface and class extension; without it, interface and class hierarchies like `interface X extends Y { extraProp: any }` or `class X extends Y { extraProp: any }` would not form *type* hierarchies and things would be difficult to reason about.

---

However, as you noticed, there are some specific situations in which the compiler warns you about unexpected extra properties.  This [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#3823](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823) only kicks in when you are assigning an *object literal* (that is, an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) value with curly braces) directly to a *non-empty* target.  See [this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#14606](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14606#issuecomment-285956509) for authoritative corroboration).

In your examples, the type `{a: number}` is non-empty, so the assignment of the object literal `{a: 42, b: 43}` to `a` produces a warning.  But the type `{}` is empty, so the assignment of the same object literal to `a` produces no warning.

Before the introduction of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) the empty object type `{}` was used everywhere to mean "any non-nullish type whatsoever" and having the compiler complain for this would have introduced a lot of unhelpful warnings.

In any case, you can think of excess property checking more as a linter rule than a type system feature.

So that's the answer for why this is happening.

---

To your last question: "What is the type that only accepts objects with value `{}`?"  Well, as I said, the type system is not geared toward *prohibiting* extra properties.  There are workarounds like [this one in microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-393202175) using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to check for excess properties and constrain them to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), but they are complicated .

In the particular case of `{}`, you can use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) with value type `never` to prohibit all properties:

```
type A = { [k: string]: never };
const a: A = { a: 42, b: 43 }; // error
const a2: A = { a: 42 }; // error
const a3: A = {}; // okay
```

I'm not sure what the use case for such a type is, but you might find it harder to use than you'd like.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAsAKCXpALgJ4zICCSAvBkiAFxLACuYARhAE5IC+O+S8APbAoBWgwrV04pABYATABokrBrIDMPANw4++ISLEh5VGvTlKVazdx259w0bXUTTxrUgD0nxoKScOQQ5dbF5sHFBIWARkAE0MPTxiUiRJDDD+AydzNOlzBWVVORs7MIjwaDhEJAAtBPskknJTaQBtAGsGUQ4AS2AAcwBdBmAIADdObUSBRyNXKRkCq2LtLx8AoOmso3l5szUTWzX-DkDghpnDZz30I+8kQXaQIhxuIA)

Comment: No use-case, just curious