# Is there a way to define a required type for just optional properties/defaults?

Tags: typescript

I'm specifying a type for a function's input. I want to make some properties required and others optional:

```
type Input = {
  // Required:
  url: string,
  method: string,

  // Optional:
  timeoutMS?: number,
  maxRedirects?: number,
}
```

I also want to define a defaults object internally, which I can copy/merge into inputs to "fill in" any omitted optional properties.

**I'd like to strongly type this defaults object** so that:

1. I can enforce that I haven't forgotten any optional property.
2. I don't need to specify any required property. (*Ideally*, I'd love to even enforce that I *can't* specify any required property.)

```
const defaults: WhatShouldThisTypeBe = {
  timeoutMS: 30000,
  maxRedirects: 5,
}
```

I know that `Required<Input>` achieves #1, but fails #2, while `Partial<Input>` achieves #2 (tho not the *ideal* #2) , but fails #1. I haven't been able to figure out how to combine those, e.g. with `&` or `|`, or use other [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to achieve both goals.

Here's a [playground link if helpful](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAUFKB6PKAJQgEdEBLAJwgBMAuHKRKgG3qgGdgqK4BzADRMAthGAALAPYMuPPkKxMCUAPJhgFKXACG7JprFTkAWQDKAfg5xEIgEYQqw3CJ0APErWoQAxsE5WUDb2jsIAvkqgkFAA6hI6wGbSiKy0ACoSFJxp4BAAQtDoAAo6VJp6ADzwSMAAfADcSj7a3FC0EABmOin+HHEJScapGVk5kAVomAYURqZmHADMAAwrS85Qrh503n6cHACs4Y1YKhkQnNCcyalQjlRSVIxYzXCtIlmcCgAind2svbF4olrulMtlchN0NhcLhDBBjMBzItVmssGFji9WhA3DwdD8uj09oCBiCRuDxoUpi5xNJZAByADiAFE0nT1nCEUioMtVutNp4dgDDmigA). Thank you!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL4RVm) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz: amazing! Yes, please do write it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important piece you need is to identify the [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of an object type programmatically.  Here's one way to do it (as long as your object type doesn't have [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)):

```
type OptionalProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Partial<Pick<T, K>> extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never
}[keyof T]
```

Because a type with an optional property like `{a?: string}` does not extend the same type with a required property like `{a: string}`, we can check to see whether an optional version of each property `K` does or does not extend the actual property.  We use [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to focus on just the part of the object with the key `K`.  If the optional version (using [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)) does extend the actual version, then the property `K` is optional and we keep it, otherwise we throw it away as `never`.  For your `Input` type, this evaluates to:

```
type OptionalInputProps = OptionalProperties<Input>
// type OptionalInputProps = "timeoutMS" | "maxRedirects"
```

From there we can just use [the `Required<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and `Pick` to grab just that part of `Input` and make its properties required:

```
type WhatShouldThisTypeBe = Required<Pick<Input, OptionalProperties<Input>>>;
/* type WhatShouldThisTypeBe = {
    timeoutMS: number;
    maxRedirects: number;
} */
```

And then things work as desired:

```
const missingDefaults: WhatShouldThisTypeBe = { // error!
  //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  //  Property 'maxRedirects' is missing
  timeoutMS: 30000,
};

const extraDefaults: WhatShouldThisTypeBe = {
  method: 'GET', // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
  //Object literal may only specify known properties
  timeoutMS: 30000,
  maxRedirects: 5,
}
```

---

Notice that `WhatShouldThisTypeBe` does not expressly *forbid* the required properties like `method`, but if you assign an object literal directly to a variable of that type, the compiler will catch it with [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).  This is not foolproof; you can get around it by doing the assignment indirectly:

```
const unannotatedWithExtras = {
  method: 'GET',
  timeoutMS: 30000,
  maxRedirects: 5,
}
const uncaughtExtraDefaults: WhatShouldThisTypeBe =
  unannotatedWithExtras; // okay, no error
```

TypeScript works this way intentionally; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69316185/2887218) and its answer for more info.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAUFKB6PKAJQgEdEBLAJwgBMAuHKRKgG3qgGdgqK4BzADRMAthGAALAPYMuPPkKxMCUAPJhgFKXACG7JprFTkAWQDKAfg5xEIgEYQqw3CJ0APErWoQAxsE5WUDb2jsIAvkqgkGoaWrqsAApUUpBUmhCcADwAKgB8aJhMANoA0lB8UADWECBSAGZQ2QC6ALSBCTppFHqZCRQ+lTmCUCW5+RBuwBBwtJxQfQNDI-kWI1DWEABujlhhRdW1Dc2R4NDqmtp68EjASSlz6Odxenep6VnXyLlYKlFnsZdWJ9bskwA8oAAiQwQYzAcwQqAAH0hrg8dG8fk4EJO0QA6hIdMAzNJEKxaNkJBRONlTgAhaDoEjkby0Xr9QbA4ZPQGvRzvTLAsa5ADcPwAVFA-lB8YTicYyRSqTTIPSCthcLhobDzNZbA4qKKNVBUZ4Mf5dSEDbsoGK8EofNpuFBaBA6jpSebpQSiSSFZTqXSGYVNRQjKYzBwAMwABlj0ecxvcppomI4AFZwsL8IQpJUdCAlCoKRloJxfbQoI5klRGFgHXAnSIqZwFAARV3u1iemU++Xk-3KiCq9AYbOVqjVgCEykIUAAfgvF0vlzPcLy0iAoAByE3olP+LflOZNzgtgQGUMw8NRuPx3aiuuOlATHg6dtuj2cDg9uWk-tKwM1VEcRpFkLcAHEAFFsi3YYVCrKQqGnXACGXNCoEyFoWhnVQ7AAK18FBWAoKYqD0RNN20VhN04SAfAoOpN0qOApAAdzgKAwFBPkKAyC8wzhCMoBjOME13Lx9y-KAM12e0n2YXQ4BY4BCToXESIkSDJjI8F1WNECZA4CDoNg-ir0Em9RNEJM90IqSZIiesnUQOAfHdfgJGALTX3fTtu29X8-QAlUGSYFydCUqQVKmWh1MkbydKzFRc3zYYWPHasgA)

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Thank you for such thorough help!

One question (hard to google): I hadn't seen `-?:` before. Are there any docs for that operator? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers